# What is need of using tags in symfony2 Services

Tags: php, symfony

I have read the symfony2 docs about [tagged services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html)

But i could not understand their example. Is there any other source or tutorial which can help me understanding why to use them

Comment: Just a different way of looking up services via the service locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [*Tags*](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#tags) section of the [*Service Container*](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html) chapter:

> In the same way that a blog post on the Web might be tagged with things such as “Symfony” or “PHP”, services configured in your container can also be tagged. In the service container, a tag implies that the service is meant to be used for a specific purpose.

Basically, you tag a service for other services and/or components to know they can use it for their specific purposes.

Comment: An example of this is Twig and Smarty extensions: `tag="smarty.extension"`. These are processed in a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) and registered to be used in templates as functions/filters.